# Serving SVG as GZIP does not cache it in subsequent requests

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4, cache, ubuntu-14.04, gzip

- **OS**: Ubuntu 14.04
- **Apache:** 2.4.12 (using PPA) - *mod_expires, mod_headers*

I am using GZIP for all SVG files. It works well with the following statement in a configuration file (not .htaccess)

```
AddType image/svg+xml .svg
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
```

However, hitting F5, the browser will request the file to the server returning a *200* Status Code instead of returning the expected *304* Status Code.

If I remove **AddOutputFilterByType** then the server returns *304* but the content is not GZIPped.

Here are some raw request headers

**NO GZIP (200 Status Code)**

```
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Cache-Control: max-age=2592000
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 689
Content-Type: image/svg+xml
Date: Thu, 02 Jul 2015 10:41:09 GMT
Etag: "2b1-5157f331b2480"
Expires: Sat, 01 Aug 2015 10:41:09 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=80
Last-Modified: Thu, 07 May 2015 15:02:26 GMT
Server: Apache
```

**NO GZIP (304 Status Code)**

```
Cache-Control: max-age=2592000
Connection: Keep-Alive
Date: Thu, 02 Jul 2015 10:39:12 GMT
Etag: "2b1-5157f331b2480"
Expires: Sat, 01 Aug 2015 10:39:12 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=71
Server: Apache
```

**With GZIP**

```
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Cache-Control: max-age=2592000
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 451
Content-Type: image/svg+xml
Date: Thu, 02 Jul 2015 10:38:45 GMT
Etag: "2b1-5157f331b2480-gzip"
Expires: Sat, 01 Aug 2015 10:38:45 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=75
Last-Modified: Thu, 07 May 2015 15:02:26 GMT
Server: Apache
Vary: Accept-Encoding
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug in Apache where it doesn't handle Etags properly for gzipped contents. Can be resolved by either turning off gzip (as you have noticed - but with the performance hit that entails) or turning off ETags (and depending on Last-Modified header for 304s - so no real loss). I prefer to turn off ETags.

There is also an alternative option (DeflateAlterETag) but only in Apache 2.5 and even that seems like a fudge to me.

More details here: [Why does Apache send 200 OK while Last-modified matches If-modified-since?](https://serverfault.com/questions/636976/why-does-apache-send-200-ok-while-last-modified-matches-if-modified-since/696832?s=7|0.0000#696832)